# Not able to download pyqt5 tools

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to install pyqt5-tools on a windows OS, every time I try this via the terminal with pip install via the terminal, I get an error saying that it is not compatible with python version 2.7, however I have python version 3.6 downloaded on my computer..

Comment: What did you try so far ? And what happened when you did that?

Comment: Looks like you have python 2.7 installed also.  You should `pip3` command.

Answer (score -1):

How do you use pip? I guess you are executing `pip install ...`. Try `pip3 install...` instead. Or execute python like normally but with `-m pip install ...` after it